# Bluetooth app doesn't work

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I found source for bluetooth between Android and Arduino
and I copied and pasted it.
It doesn't show any error in code.
When I try to run this, it truns off with message

```
"Fatal Error - In onResume() and an exception occureed during write :
socket closde. Check that the SPP
UUID:00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb exists on server"
```

What is the problem and what should I do?

Here is source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "bluetooth1";

Button btnOn, btnOff;

private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private OutputStream outStream = null;

// SPP UUID service
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

// MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
private static String address = "00:15:FF:F2:19:5F";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn);
    btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff);

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    checkBTState();

    btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendData("1");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendData("0");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
        try {
            final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRFCommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
            return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        }
    }
    return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e1.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
    try {
        btSocket.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "...Connection ok...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

    try {
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

    if (outStream != null) {
        try {
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    try     {
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}

private void checkBTState() {
    // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if(btAdapter==null) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
    } else {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
        } else {
            //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}

private void errorExit(String title, String message){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}

private void sendData(String message) {
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

    Log.d(TAG, "...Send data: " + message + "...");

    try {
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
        if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
            msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 35 in the java code";
        msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

        errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad code, you should not use it - there is a great sample from Google - BluetoothChatService: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat . See BluuetoothChatService class. Unfortunately, there is problem with it- it uses Handler for communicating with the rest of a app. I change it a bit so it posts messages to another HandlerThread and that thread notifies custom interface set by user (for my Arduino project), for more details see this project: https://github.com/AlexShutov/LEDLights

Comment: thanks for sharing your code :) i will refer to this and make code. thanks again